# Tensorflow lite error! ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got tensor of type 0 but expected type 1 for input 21

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a pb format weight file, then I convert it to tflite format for mobile device deploying. However, my model have two inputs, one for image (dims: 1*3*36*60), another for a vector (dims: 1*2). When I validate the tflite format model, my code shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing import image

img = image.load_img('f01_70_-0.5890_-0.3927.png', target_size=(36, 60))
head_angle = np.array([[-0.3619980211517256, -0.44335020008101705]])
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.contrib.lite.Interpreter(model_path="pupilModel.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

#print(input_details)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], x)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[1]['index'], head_angle)
interpreter.invoke()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

output logs shown below:

```
[{'name': 'inputs/input_img', 'index': 22, 'shape': array([ 1, 36, 60,  3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}, 
{'name': 'inputs/head_angle', 'index': 21, 'shape': array([1, 2], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]

File "/Users/jackie/Downloads/pupil_model/tf_to_lite.py", line 22, in <module>
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[1]['index'], head_angle)
File "/Users/jackie/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/interpreter.py", line 156, in set_tensor
    self._interpreter.SetTensor(tensor_index, value)
  File "/Users/jackie/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.py", line 133, in SetTensor
    return _tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.InterpreterWrapper_SetTensor(self, i, value)
ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got tensor of type 0 but expected type 1 for input 21
```

My question is that how to validate the tflite model with two outputs?

Answer (score 1):

The `head_angle` `np.array` doesn't have the `int32` type that TFLite requires.

Try the following change:

```
head_angle = np.array([[-0.3619980211517256, -0.44335020008101705]], dtype=np.int32)
```